# Preseed partitioning - total capacity issues

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, lvm, preseed

I'm trying to get a Preseed file working on a 111GB hard drive and it seems there is not enough space. Basically what I want to do:

`/boot 512MB`

`vg1 40GB`

`vg2 70GB`

Some logical volumes in each of the volume groups.

The problem that I am encountering is the following:

How does preseed exactly work on the creation of physical partitions, VGs and LVs?

It tells me that i need `147930 MB` for the expert-recipe and I only have available `119453 MB`.

When it creates the logical volumes it doesn't know that the space for those logical volumes will be allocated from the volume groups already created? It allocates the free space for LVs directly from /dev/sda? If so, how can I tell it to allocate it from each VG?

This is the expert-recipe:

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe recipe1 :: \
            511 512 512 ext4                        \
            $primary{ }                             \
            $bootable{ }                            \
            method{ format }                        \
            format{ }                               \
            use_filesystem{ }                       \
            filesystem{ ext4 }                      \
            device{ /dev/sda1 }                     \
            mountpoint{ /boot } .                   \
            39999 40000 40000 ext4                  \
            $primary{ }                             \
            method{ lvm }                           \
            device{ /dev/sda2 }                     \
            vg_name{ rootvg } .                     \
            69999 70000 70000 ext4                  \
            $primary{ }                             \
            method{ lvm }                           \
            device{ /dev/sda3 }                     \
            vg_name{ infravg } .                    \
            100 1 100000 ext4                       \
            method{ format }                        \
            format{ }                               \
            use_filesystem{ }                       \
            filesystem{ ext4 }                      \
            mountpoint{ /part1 } .                  \
            5999 1 6000 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ var_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /var } .                    \
            3999 1 4000 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ usr_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /usr } .                    \
            4999 1 5000 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ root_lv }                      \
            method{ format }                        \
            format{ }                               \
            use_filesystem{ }                       \
            filesystem{ ext4 }                      \
            mountpoint{ / } .                       \
            1999 1 2000 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ home_lv }                      \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /home } .                   \
            4999 1 5000 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ tmp_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /tmp } .                    \
            8000 1 8000 linux-swap                  \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ swap }                         \
            method{ swap } format{ } .              \
            999 1 1000 ext4                         \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ opt_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /opt } .                    \
            128 1 128 ext4                          \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ system_lv }                    \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /system } .                 \
            100 1 100000 ext4                       \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ free1_lv }                     \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /part2 } .                  \
            1000 1 1024 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ infravg }              \
            lv_name{ chef_lv }                      \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /opt/chef } .               \
            4999 1 5000 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ infravg }              \
            lv_name{ images_lv }  5000                  \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /images } .                 \
            100 1 1000000 ext4                      \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ infravg }              \
            lv_name{ free2_lv }                     \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /part3 }                    \
            .
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some research (to the 4th,5th page of google searches!) I read (and I'm also pretty sure it's true) that partman/preseed will calculate total size as sum of the size of all the partitions, it doesn't matter if there are LV partitions which are part of a VG.

If I add the maximum size numbers, indeed, I am getting ~147000 MB. So, what I did to solve this issue? Well, for starters I decreased the minimum size of the partitions in the preseed file to 1/4 or 1/2 of the maximum size, then set all the priorities higher or equal to the maximum size (you can find [here](https://www.bishnet.net/tim/blog/2015/01/29/understanding-partman-autoexpert_recipe/) and [here](http://ask.debian.net/questions/preseed-and-recipe-with-lvm-expert-recipe-too-large) some additional information regarding this)

This allowed partman/preseed to create all the partitions succesfully, even though they weren't the right size.

In order to achieve the right size I added a late_command script which resized all the logical volumes to their correct size.

Also, to keep all the free space that would remain if partitioning were to be done manually, I created dummy partitions which I later deleted in the same late_command script.

I know it's unorthodox but it's the only way to work with preseed/partman.

Here is also the partitioning recipe:

```
d-i partman/early_command string debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$(list-devices disk | head -n1)"
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string rootvg
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string 34%
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string infravg
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string 60%
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select diod
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe diod :: \
            511 512 512 ext4                        \
            $primary{ }                             \
            $bootable{ }                            \
            method{ format }                        \
            format{ }                               \
            use_filesystem{ }                       \
            filesystem{ ext4 }                      \
            device{ /dev/sda1 }                     \
            mountpoint{ /boot } .                   \
            39999 40000 40000 ext4                  \
            $primary{ }                             \
            method{ lvm }                           \
            device{ /dev/sda2 }                     \
            vg_name{ rootvg } .                     \
            69999 70000 70000 ext4                  \
            $primary{ }                             \
            method{ lvm }                           \
            device{ /dev/sda3 }                     \
            vg_name{ infravg } .                    \
            100 1000 -1 ext4                        \
            method{ format }                        \
            format{ }                               \
            use_filesystem{ }                       \
            filesystem{ ext4 }                      \
            mountpoint{ /part1 } .                  \
            128 1000 128 ext4                       \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ system_lv }                    \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /system } .                 \
            100 1500 1000 ext4                      \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ opt_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /opt } .                    \
            100 2500 2000 ext4                      \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ home_lv }                      \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /home } .                   \
            100 4500 4000 ext4                     \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ usr_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /usr } .                    \
            100 6000 5000 ext4                     \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ root_lv }                      \
            method{ format }                        \
            format{ }                               \
            use_filesystem{ }                       \
            filesystem{ ext4 }                      \
            mountpoint{ / } .                       \
            100 5500 5000 ext4                     \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ tmp_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /tmp } .                    \
            100 6500 6000 ext4                     \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ var_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /var } .                    \
            100 7500 8000 linux-swap               \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ swap }                         \
            method{ swap } format{ } .              \
            100 1000 -1 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ free1_lv }                     \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /part2 } .                  \
            100 2000 1024 ext4                      \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ infravg }              \
            lv_name{ chef_lv }                      \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /opt/chef } .               \
            100 4000 5000 ext4                      \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ infravg }              \
            lv_name{ images_lv }                    \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /images } .                 \
            100 1000 -1 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ infravg }              \
            lv_name{ free2_lv }                     \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /part3 }                    \
            .
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select Finish
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
```